# How to run TensorRT based deep learning model as real time?

Tags: real-time, rtos, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt

I have optimized my deep learning model with **TensorRT**. A C++ interface is inferencing images by optimized model on **Jetson TX2**. This interface is providing average 60 FPS (But it is not stable. Inferences are in range 50 and 160 FPS). I need to run this system as **real time on real time patched Jetson**.

So what is your thoughts on real time inference with TensorRT? Is it possible to develop real time inferencing system with TensorRT and how?

I have tried set high priorities to process and threads to provide preemption. I expect appoximatly same FPS value on every inference. So I need deterministic inference time. But system could not output deterministicaly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the clock on Jetson: `sudo nvpmodel -m 0`

Here is some links for more information:

- https://elinux.org/Jetson/Performance
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999915/jetson-tx2/how-do-you-switch-between-max-q-and-max-p/post/5109507/#5109507
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1000345/jetson-tx2/two-cores-disabled-/post/5110960/#5110960

Comment: Yes. I am using both "sudo ~/jetson_clocks.sh" and "sudo nvpmodel -m 0" commands. They're improving performance but what i need to do is deterministic inferencing.

Comment: By deterministic inference, do you mean getting the same results for the same inputs to inference?

Comment: He wants stable fps.

Comment: Yes, I exactly want "stable fps".